# How do I refill my PP?

Tags: earthbound

Sleeping in a hotel seems to refill my HP but not my PP. How do I refill my PP? Do I have to sleep in a certain place or use a certain item?

Comment: Use more water.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several options for restoring your PP in Earthbound.

1. Sleeping will always restore you PP. This is typically done at hotels.
2. Touching a magic butterfly will restore 20pp to every character. These are not limited but rather have a chance to spawn at certain locations when visiting areas.
3. Consuming certain items such as PSI caramels (limited in supply) or Brain Food Lunches (sold towards the end of the game). The fourth character can recover PP by drinking water.
4. Lucky Sandwiches, if you're willing to deal with some randomness, or exploit the RNG. [Details here.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/588301-earthbound/41195966)
5. Paula and the fourth character can learn the PSI Magnet line of abilities, which allow them to semi-reliably drain PP from enemies.

Comment: Oh, so it did restore and I just used it up too fast to notice? Go me, I am a brilliant human.

Comment: Magic butterflies are, in fact, not limited. They have a chance to spawn in particular locations every time you go there.

Comment: @Nick Huh, in nearly 20 years of playing Earthbound I never knew that. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Ness cannot learn PSI Magnet. The fourth character can.

Comment: @Keen Updated. Now I've shamed myself twice in the same answer

Comment: Other PP-restorative items you encounter later in the game include Bottle of Water, DXBottle of Water, Magic Tarts, Magic Truffles, and Magic Pudding. Take note that some items will be more or less effective on certain characters.